# Generator List not working with CSV library

Tags: python-2.7, csv, generator

I have this CSV file:

```
C204,F2,1,W,
C104,F2,10,W,
C004,F2,10,S,
```

And in my code I have:

```
STR = csv.reader(open('CSV.txt', 'rb'))

website = [row[3] for row in STR if row[3] == 'W']
school  = [row[3] for row in STR if row[3] == 'S']

print website, school
```

When I run the code it prints: `['W', 'W'] []`
Instead of: `['W', 'W'] ['S']`
And if I flip the assignments then the opposite prints out: `[] ['S']`

I can fix it by placing `STR = csv.reader(open('CSV.txt', 'rb'))` between the `website` and `school`

Is there a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csv.reader` object is an iterator. It's not a list or any other sequence type. You can only use an iterator once. After that it's exhausted and you can't iterate on it again (it acts as if it is empty if you try). This is why the second list to create is always empty.

You can work around this in a few different ways. As you mention in your next to last paragraph, one way to avoid the issue is to recreate the iterator after consuming it the first time.

Another solution is to dump the data from the iterator into a list (which you can then iterate on as many times as you want):

```
with open('CSV.txt', 'rb') as f:   # this is a better way to handle opening files
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)     # read all the data into a list

website = [row[3] for row in data if row[3] == 'W']
school  = [row[3] for row in data if row[3] == 'S']
```

A final approach is to use a regular `for` loop rather than a list comprehension so that you can make just a single pass over the data:

```
website = []
school = []

with open('CSV.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[3] == 'W':
            website.append(row[3])
        elif row[3] == 'S':
            school.append(row[3])
```